# Installing ikiwiki on nginx - fastcgi/fcgi wrapper

Tags: nginx, fcgi

My ultimate goal is to setup ikiwiki, my current goal is to get a fcgi wrapper working for nginx, so I can move on to the next step...

The ikiwiki page points out this page as an example for a fcgi wrapper:

http://technotes.1000lines.net/?p=23

So far I've installed the ikiwiki and libfcgi-perl modules through aptitude:

```
aptitude install libfcgi-perl
aptitude install ikiwiki
```

It installed those packages as well as some minimal dependency packages.

So the next step following the guide at technotes, I grabbed http://technotes.1000lines.net/fastcgi-wrapper.pl but I'm not sure where to actually place this file... do I run it as a service?

The script makes a socket file in /var/run/nginx but that directory does not exist.. do I manually create it?

So in addition to the .pl file for the cgi wrapper, I need to also define a separate cgi file for parameters. If my conf looks like this...

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name notes.domain.org;

        access_log /www/notes/public_html/notes.domain.org/log/access.log;
        error_log /www/notes/public_html/notes.domain.org/log/error.log;

        location / {
                root /www/notes/public_html/notes.domain.org/public/;
                index index.html;
        }

  }
```

And I don't have a cgi-bin directory, where exactly should I create it within my structure, and regarding that I'd obviously have to update the below before I include it in my conf, but I'm just not exactly sure how this would work out.

```
# /cgi-bin configuration
location ~ ^/cgi-bin/.*\.cgi$ {
  gzip off;
  fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/nginx/perl_cgi-dispatch.sock;  [1]*
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /www/blah.com$fastcgi_script_name; [2]*
  include fastcgi_params; [3]*
}
```

Also since the user is www-data and `/var/run` is root owned, what's the proper way of giving it access?

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you should install **fcgiwrap** via apitude.
worked out of the box.

most of the nginx tutorials suck, because they are either not debian-specific, try to reinvent the wheel or use old software or configuration. so be careful and read a bit more than usual.

fyi, my cgi location block:

```
location ~ \.cgi {
        root    /usr/lib;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
          # Fastcgi parameters, include the standard ones
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        # Adjust non standard parameters (SCRIPT_FILENAME)
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/lib$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  AUTH_USER          $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER    $remote_user;

}
```

the /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;
```

the ikiwiki stuff goes in /usr/lib/cgi-bin, you can reach it via http://server/cgi-bin/